# How can I communicate from a DLL to a calling application in C++

Tags: c++, windows, dll, hook

I created a system wide hook DLL and in my DLL I am trying to get notified each time a new process is created or destroyed. Whenever a new process is being detected, I want to be able to send a message to the calling program, be it a Boolean value or a custom object.

How can I do this? At the moment I am using a file to log all names, which is horrible. This is the code so far:

**def file**

```
;LIBRARY
; Def file
EXPORTS
    InstallHook
    UninstallHook
```

**dllapi.h**

```
void InstallHook(void);
void UninstallHook(void);
```

**dllmain.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h" 

using namespace std;
HINSTANCE currentProcessHandle;
HHOOK hookID;
string str = "1";
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    if (ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
        currentProcessHandle = hModule;
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int nCode, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{

    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wparam, lparam);

    std::ofstream outfile;
    CBT_CREATEWND   *CBTHOOKCREATE;
    RECT            *CBTRECTPTR;
    RECT            CBTRECT;
    wstring         Message;

    CBTHOOKCREATE = (CBT_CREATEWND*) lparam;
    LPWSTR str = L"                     ";
    outfile.open(("d:\\test.txt"), std::ios_base::app);

    if (nCode >= 0) {
        switch (nCode)
        {
        case HCBT_CREATEWND:
            outfile << *(CBTHOOKCREATE->lpcs->lpszName) << " " << CBTHOOKCREATE->lpcs->lpszName << " Created!~ " << endl;
            //cout << "Created!~" << endl;
            break;
        case HCBT_DESTROYWND:
            outfile << "Destroyed!~" << endl;
            //cout << "Destroyed!~" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            //cout << "something else" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}

void InstallHook(void)
{
    hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookProcedure, currentProcessHandle, 0);
}

void UninstallHook(void)
{ 
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID);
}
```

**Hook Consumer console application**

```
// Hook Executer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\Dll\dllapi.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num = -1;
    cout << "1.Install Hook"<<endl
        << "2.Unistall Hook"<<endl
        << "0.Exit";
    do{
        cin >> num;
        if (num ==1)
        {
            InstallHook();

        }
        else
        {
            UninstallHook();
        }
        getchar();
        system("cls");
        cout << "1.Install Hook" << endl
            << "2.Unistall Hook" << endl
            << "0.Exit";
    } while (num != 0 && num < 3);
    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hook DLL is loaded, by Windows, in the address spaces on the hooked processes. You will have to use IPC. See [Interprocess Communications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574.aspx) for a starter.

One simple IPC, usable in such a case, may be [Data Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648710.aspx).

Note that Data Copy requires an active (pumped) message queue in the receiving thread.

One possible way to implement that (many others possible):

You add a secondary thread to your EXE, with a pumped message queue. In the new thread, you will create a dummy invisible windows, with a specific class name.

The code for that is a very classic sequence: `RegisterClass`, `CreateWindow`, `while GetMessage DispatchMessage`

In the Hook DLL, you will have a global `HWND` variable. When wanting to use `WM_COPYDATA`, if the global variable is null, use `FindWindow` to retrieve the `HWND`, and store it for next use. That code will be executed a least one time in each hooked process.

You may want to use the [SendMessageTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644952.aspx) API to send the `WM_COPYDATA` message.

Note that if you stop/restart your exe quickly, some processes may have an invalid HWND stored in the global variable. Check the return value of the Send API, and if it's "invalid hwnd", redo the `FindWindow`. (not sure if that's kind of behavior is really possible, but anyway...)

Also note, that your main thread should wait for the correct creation of the dummy window in the secondary thread before installing the hook.

If your hooking EXE is a Windowed one, you don't need a secondary thread, but you will have to build a GUI. You could also, perhaps, stay with "only one thread" and manage to juggle with some APIs, to have at the same time an active message queue and your `getchar` code, but I don't recommend that.